# How can I unserialize a numpy array that was cast to a bytestring?

Tags: python, numpy

I need to serialize a numpy array to some JSON-compatible form.  Since the framework I'm using doesn't give me access to the JSON encoder/decoder object, I'm stuck serializing a numpy array to something that can *then* be marshalled into JSON.  I've opted for either `array.tobytes` or `array.tostring` (both seem to be essentially the same thing).

Below is an example which illustrates my problem:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.rand(1024, 1024)  # create array of random values
b = array.tobytes()  # serialize array
a2 = np.fromstring(b)
```

When I inspect the value of `a2`, I find that it only contains the first line of the original `a`.  In other words, `a2 == a[0, :]`.

How can I decode the full array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually numpy.fromstring() returns a single dimensional array of 1024X1024 intead of a 2 Dimensional array, All you need to do is reshape into 1024X1024,

Try this :-

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.rand(1024, 1024)  # create array of random values
b = array.tobytes()
np.fromstring(b).reshape(1024,1024)
```

Comment: Thanks!  Is there a way to preserve the shape information when serializing?  I can't expect the un-serialization end to know anything about the array dimensions *a priori*.

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't, you could probably write a wrapper class around numpy for the same and use that class too probably at the un-serialization end, I don't really know of a cleaner way.

Comment: Cleaner solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30698004/how-can-i-serialize-a-numpy-array-e-g-to-string-while-preserving-matrix-dimen?lq=1